# simple form input field as plain text not manually editable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

I'm using simple_forms gem to create a form for my model.

The model contains some fields that are the result of javascript calculations based on other fields, so I would like to have them represented as text, instead of an input field, so that graphically they don't seem editable and don't confuse people.

Here's what I have so far in my view:

```
- field = "time_quantity"
  %strong{:id => "#{field}_str", :class => "text-success"}
    = f.object[field]
  = f.input field, as: :hidden, input_html: {value: f.object[field]}
```

the text in the `%strong` writes the value as text, the subsequent input field is what is inserted in the model with the form.

Also the problem with this is that if I input wrong data for these fields I won't be seeing any error notice next to them, because it will be hidden. As shown here:

```
<strong class="text-success" id="time_quantity_str" data-original-title="" title=""></strong>
<div class="input hidden project_time_quantity field_with_errors">
  <input class="hidden input-medium" id="project_time_quantity" name="project[time_quantity]" type="hidden">
  <span class="error">can't be blank</span>
</div>
```

I would like to change this to something like:

```
- field = "time_quantity"
  %strong{:id => "#{field}_str", :class => "text-success"}
    = f.input field, as: :plain, input_html: {value: f.object[field]}
```

to have more DRY in the view and in the javascript.

How do you think it could be possible to achieve this?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I think either you should use a disabled input or you can use a label field as well.Try like this:

```
<%= f.input :field_name, disabled: true, hint: 'You cannot change this field' %>
```

or

```
<%= f.label :field_name %>
```

Hope it will help.Thanks

Comment: Thanks, the first option kinda solves it, although graphically is not what I was looking for. Maybe I can change the look & feel of that input field to be looking like a label? would you know how to get this with bootstrap?